# Database design for email and sms

Tags: php, mysql, database, relational-database

I have a system already in production and now I need to add a new functionality: Send and store (log) email and text messages (sms).

Basically I will need a table to create templates for the emails/text messages, allowing to add placeholders that will be replaced dynamically when the message is sent (like title, first name, last name, etc).

My doubt is: Text messages are really short (maybe that's why they are called SMS :D) and emails can be really long. I can have one single table to store both text and emails: I just need to add a TEXT or MEDIUMTEXT field. But it looks like a "waste" in case of the text messages (where maybe a simple varchar will do the job).

Also, there are email webhooks (and sms webhooks) that will allow to know if the messages are being actually delivered to the recipients.

Will it cause me lots of problems in long term to store everything in the same DB structure? Or is it better to create two different structures: one for emails and one for SMS?

Comment: text(if same table structures) is better in my view.because now days every sms service providers support 1000 character length message .if two tables set length as your wish

Comment: TEXT fields only take up as much space as needed. Putting a small string in a TEXT field won't waste anything. See [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-innodb).

Comment: What database driver you use? MySQLi?

Comment: Also note the subtle but important difference between delivery to the recipient's mail server, delivery to the recipient's actual mailbox, and opening/reading of the message. The sender can only reliably detect the first.

Comment: @halojoy: I'm using Laravel with MySQL. I'm not sure what driver it uses internally, but I guess is some extension of MySQLi